# I get null array after adding object to it while retrieving the data from mongodb database in express using find() method

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I want to send the array to the another file But
I get null array after adding object to it using push() method in for-loop while retrieving data from mongodb database using find() method in express

```
const mongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";

exports.retriveArray = () => {
    var ar = [];
    mongoClient.connect(url, (err, db) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        var database = db.db('fortask');
        database.collection('Task').find({}, { projection: { _id: 0 } }).toArray((err, res) => {
            if (err) throw err;

            for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
                ar.push(res[i].Task);
            }
            db.close();
        });
    });
    console.log(ar);
    return ar;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a asynchronous problem what you have here. You send data back but the asynchronous task isnt done yet. Here a solution

```
const mongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";

exports.retriveArray = () => {
    var ar = [];
    return new Promise((resolve)=> {
       mongoClient.connect(url, (err, db) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        var database = db.db('fortask');
        database.collection('Task').find({}, { projection: { _id: 0 } }).toArray((err, res) => {
            if (err) throw err;

            for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
                ar.push(res[i].Task);
            } 
            resolve(ar);
            db.close();
        });
    });
    })

}
```

Then you wrap your import into IIFE

```
(async()=> {
   var arr = await retrieve.retriveArray();
})()
```

Comment: Now it shows this error         UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)

Comment: i have wrapped everything in `try.. catch`, how do you import this file?

Comment: Using this line,  const retrieve = require('./retrieveTask');
var arr = retrieve.retriveArray();  , retrieveTask is the file name above

Comment: Hey it works ....why it is "()" at the end int (async()=> {
   var arr = await retrieve.retriveArray();
})() and what is IIFE

Comment: IIFE means Immendantly invoked express function, it gets executed Immendantly. Google for it for more info

Answer (score 1):

The problem in this code is you `ar` is outside the callback and print the output before the function update the `ar`. so callback function go into the event loop and the next statement is executed. I think You can find the similar Question on stack overflow

```
const mongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
    const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";

exports.retriveArray = () => {
    var ar = [];
    return mongoClient.connect(url, (err, db) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        var database = db.db('fortask');
        return database.collection('Task').find({}, { projection: { _id: 0 } }).toArray((err, res) => {
            if (err) throw err;

            for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
                ar.push(res[i].Task);
            }
            db.close();
            console.log(ar);
            return ar;
        });
    });

}
```

Comment: you are returning `ar` in a callback function this wont work

Comment: It print array in console fine but it send the null array to the another file where i need it

Comment: as i said you return the response in an callback function, this wont work either

Comment: @Ifaruki Copy my Code and check report issue do you have or make any demo function like and check if you found any issue then shoot you comment here

Comment: Still it print on console but in another file where is tried it to print then it show 'undefined'

Comment: @HemantSood I have added three returns check do added these three returns? or copy code and replace with your code

Comment: i copied your whole solution

Comment: Let me check,  i didn't try your recent solution